# reuse database connection in php

Tags: php

Every time I execute the php page, a new DB connection is established. How do I reuse the same connection next time?

register.php

```
include_once("../../cons/connection.php");
$can_data=mysql_query("SELECT sm.id, sm.new_reg_no, sm.name, 
....
  ORDER BY new_reg_no ASC");
$count = mysql_num_rows($can_data);
```

connection.php

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$dbhandle){
        echo 'Unable to Connect DB';
}else{
    mysql_select_db("company_accnt") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I am looking for a simple solution that can be implemented without making too many changes to the code. mysql_connect may be obsolete but that is what the legacy code is using and I need to live with it.

Comment: Since you're already using `include_once()`, the scripts in `connection.php` should be executed only once. What do you mean by "reuse the same connection next time?"

Comment: What do you mean "a new connection"? If you are not using mod_php - php process dies after page generation and you'll need to reconnect to DB every request.

Comment: Can't you just pass `$dbhandle` to `mysql_select_db()`? `mysql_select_db("company_accnt", $dbhandle)`

Comment: check [mysql_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) and this link [Persistent Database Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated consider using PDO or mysqli

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd be cautious using `mysql_pconnect.` Be sure to see the warning and read through some of the user messages in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php).

Comment: @user4035 Next time when I call register.php for another student it should some-how remember the connection from previous call and reuse it if the connection is still available. This will help me to reduce the number of DB connections.

Answer (score 3):

### using mysql_pconnect()

When you call `mysql_pconnect()` php module keeps MySQL connections even page's execution is ended. Next `mysql_pconnect()` call returns exsiting MySQL connection, so that connection is reused. This is automatically done by Apache's PHP Module.

But as others metioned, `mysql_xxxx()` functions are deprecated. We highly recommend using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO.

### Persistence option for `MySQLi`

set `mysqli.allow_persistent`=1 if you use `MySQLi`. You can find what it means at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.allow-persistent